# BASH - Positional Parameters

Tags: bash

I'm wondering if this could be possible:

scriptname: `testing`

```
#! /bin/bash
i=2

arg=`echo "$"$i`

echo $arg      #value should be the value of $2 and not just '$2' string

echo $2

exit 0
```

command: `testing a b`

output

```
$2

b
```

Is there a way to make the value of $arg equal to the value of $2 which is "b" instead of just displaying the string "$2" aside from just directly assigning the value of $2 to $arg, arg=$2?

Tried doing this arg=`echo ${$i}` but I get this error: testing: ${$i}: bad substitution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes; you can use *indirect expansion*, which looks like this:

```
i=2
arg="${!i}"          # equivalent to:    arg="$2"
```

See the fourth paragraph of [§3.5.3 "Shell Parameter Expansion" in the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).